# Python : Regex, Finding Repetitions on a string

Tags: python, regex

I need to find repetitions in a text string.
I already found a very nice elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079797/detect-repetitions-in-string) from @Tim Pietzcker

I am happy with the solution as is but would like to know whether it's possible to extend it little further such that it would accept a string with whitespaces.

For example `"a bcab c"` would return `[(abc,2)]`

I tried using the regex pattern `"([^\s]+?)\1+")` with no luck.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if in python, you could simply do `no_whitespaces = input_str.replace(" ","")` and then do your regex on `no_whitespaces`

Comment: Hi e.s, That is one possibility but my application is to find the patterns on a bigger text structure. so whenever possible would like to keep the spaces between them because I am planning to highlight the found text once the match is made

Comment: If you want to highlight the found text once the match is made, as per your above example the output should be [(a bc,2)] ? If not, how are you going to highlight the text once the match is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about removing " " from the text first. You can do it by regex itself.

```
>>> def repetitions(s):
...    r = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
...    for match in r.finditer(re.sub(r'\s+',"",s)):
...        yield (match.group(1), len(match.group(0))/len(match.group(1)))
...
```

Output.

```
>>> list(repetitions("a bcab c"))
[('abc', 2)]
```

If you still want to retain the space in the original text, Try this regex: `r"(\s*\S+\s*?\S*?)\1+"` . But this has limitations.

```
>>> def repetitions(s):
...    r = re.compile(r"(\s*\S+\s*?\S*?)\1+")
...    for match in r.finditer(s):
...        yield (match.group(1), len(match.group(0))/len(match.group(1)))
...
```

Results:

```
>>> list(repetitions(" abc abc "))
[(' abc', 2)]
>>> list(repetitions("abc abc "))
[('abc ', 2)]
>>> list(repetitions(" ab c ab c "))
[(' ab c', 2)]
>>> list(repetitions("ab cab c "))
[('ab c', 2)]
>>> list(repetitions("blablabla"))
[('bla', 3)]
```

Comment: Thanks Sanooj, I ended up replacing spaces and then matching the group back in with with a newly compiled regex with added spaces. For example the match "abc", will be fed into a new regex with "\s*".join('abc'). Thanks, heaps for your time again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(\S+ ?\S?)\1`, you can make it tolerable to spaces for strings as below where the positions of the spaces are in the same location in the repetetive words `ab c`.

```
ab cab c
```

However, if the space locations in the repetitive words are not the same. Then it means, you have to replace the meaningless spaces with an empty string `""` to find the repetitive words with your approach.

Comment: Hi Faith , Thanks heaps for your input, but spaces are irregular as shown in my example